# Read and Convert .pdf files to .txt files in R faster?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, pdftotext

I am trying to .pdf files (most of which are image based) to .txt files in bulk. The below program successfully converts both text and image based pdfs to text files.

My problem is that there is a set of ~15 pdf files that take a really long time to convert. They aren't particularly large (maximum pages between 10 to 600) but my program takes about 45 mins to convert them.

Why is it taking so long to convert them and how can I speed it up? I am using CRAN RGui(64-bit) and the R version 3.5.0

The .pdf files are in the following hirarchy

1. My Directory->Sub-folder 1->abc.pdf
2. My Directory->Sub-folder 2->def.pdf

etc..

The code is as below:

```
programdir<-"C:\\My directory"

# Delete all txt files in the path
file.remove(list.files(path=programdir, pattern = ".txt", recursive = T, full.names = T))
# Get list of sub folders in the main directory 
mydir<-list.dirs(path=programdir,full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

# Loop through sub-folders, starting from 2 as 1 is the parent directory
for(i in 2:length(mydir)) { 
    # make a vector of PDF file names
    myfiles <- list.files(path=mydir[i],pattern = ".pdf",
                          full.names = TRUE,recursive = TRUE)

    # Loop through every file in the sub-directory 
    for(j in 1:length(myfiles)) {

        # Render pdf to png image
        img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(myfiles[j], format = 'tiff',  dpi = 400)

        # Extract text from png image
        pdftotext <- ocr(img_file)

        # Ensure text files are named as  per sub-directory name_pdf name.txt format
        fname = paste(mydir[i],basename(file_path_sans_ext(myfiles[j])),sep="_")

        # Save files to directory path
        sink(file=paste(fname , ".txt", sep=''))
        writeLines(unlist(lapply(pdftotext , paste, collapse=" ")))
        sink()

        j <- j + 1  # Next file in sub-directory
    }
    i <- i + 1  # Next sub-directory record
}
file.remove(list.files(pattern = ".tiff", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE))
```

Comment: I did not test it, but you could try the multicore package with mclapply()

Comment: Package {foreach} is easy to use to parallelize your loops. I have a tutorial [there](https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/). You should loop through your files directly and try to order them by decreasing size. It's hard to help you without a reproducible example.

Comment: @F.Privé I will try my code using for each and will provide the results here thank you for the help.